# Sourceforge menu's, cant' seem to find the jQuery function that generates them?

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm digging around sourceforge's cool menus, but can't seem to find where exactly in the javascript they generate them?

I realize the layout is in html/css, but where are the events/functions on the jQuery side?

Comment: How do you know they involve any Javascript at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pure html/css, check out the css file and search for the classes flyout, yui-g + inner. Or just use firebug to see what is going on.